# "Unhandled event loop exception" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I created a "plugin with a view" on Eclipse that I later modified using a tutorial I found on the internet. I can open it and add it to the Java Perspective, but when I try to move it to another location in my perspective, the view closes and I get a "Unhandled event loop exception".

Here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.FastViewPane.hideView(FastViewPane.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.hideFastView(Perspective.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.setActiveFastView(Perspective.java:1933)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.setActiveFastView(Perspective.java:1952)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.toggleFastView(Perspective.java:2365)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.toggleFastView(WorkbenchPage.java:3972)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.hideFastView(WorkbenchPage.java:3960)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.FastViewPane$2.dragStart(FastViewPane.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.FastViewPane$2.dragStart(FastViewPane.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation$1.handleEvent(TabbedStackPresentation.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.fireEvent(AbstractTabFolder.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.fireEvent(AbstractTabFolder.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.handleDragStarted(AbstractTabFolder.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder$2.handleEvent(AbstractTabFolder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.ui.presentations.PresentationUtil.handleMouseMove(PresentationUtil.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.ui.presentations.PresentationUtil.access$4(PresentationUtil.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.ui.presentations.PresentationUtil$2.handleEvent(PresentationUtil.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Some hours ago, I didn't have this error anymore, and now it's reappearing.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Link to tutorial you referred?

Comment: I used the beginning of this tutorial since I am new to plugins and to plugins with a view 
http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/projects/Bals10b-EclipsePlugins.pdf
I stopped near p.14, since I thought I got the hang of how to modify a view.

Comment: @AmandeepJiddewar Sorry, I forgot to tag you! Read the previous comment, sorry.

Comment: I found a workaround; right-clicking on my view tab and using the "Move" action works. I guess that the error doesn't always happen.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your View's setFocus() method correctly implemented, i.e. you must call setFocus() for a SWT control that is part of your View in there.
Here's a typical example, assuming 'text' is an SWT Text widget declared as a field:

```
    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
        text.setFocus();
    }
```

Also see: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=110354#c15